# Instagram like Profile Page iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, instagram

I'm trying to make Instagram profile page like scrolling

Basically it's scrolling whole page, The top is a header, and there is a segment controller and then there are collection view.

I'm trying to do the same, but it doesn't look smooth. And I have to handle all the scrollers manually.

I also tried to add the header as part of CollectionView as **UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader**, but it only working well if the collection view is just one.

In my case, there are three collection views(for 3 segments), and they are inside another scroll view. So Can't just add the header in any of the collection views according to my current design.

Does anyone have any good solution for this, or have done something similar?

Instagram Profile page reference: [Instagram Profile Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7T2l.jpg)

Comment: "It doesn't look smooth" - that can mean anything as we have no idea how you've implemented this in code. I bet Instagram is using a single collection view, not 3, and simply using a custom layout that pins the "header" as you scroll.

Comment: Yes, when I said It doesn't look smooth, it meant it not so good to show and maybe not the right direction I'm going into.

I want to know how Instagram is doing it mainly, I'm so sure they are not doing it with a single collection view. They are using multiple.

I can clearly see the multiple collection views, when scrolling horizontally.